# Call to undefined method isMethod on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Here is my problem I'm following the [symfony tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) (Handling form submission) but I've the error "Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::isMethod()" and I can't fix it.
I read in some website that isMethod was suppressed, but I can't find another way to perform my check.
Thanks.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function contactusAction(Request $request)
    {   
    $contact = new ContactUs(); 
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($contact)
        ->add('nom', 'text')
        ->add('mail', 'email')
        ->add('sujet', 'choice', array('choices' => array('pt' => 'Problemes techniques', 'bi' => 'Boite a idees', 'd' => 'Divers')))
        ->add('msg', 'textarea')
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) 
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            echo 'OK!';         
            //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
        }
        else
            echo 'KO!!';
        }

    return $this->render('MyCoreBundle:Info:contactus.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        //return array();
    }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update Symfony to the recent version or use

```
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod())
```

Also, be aware that the compared method string should be in uppercase.

Comment: Thanks it works. I can't upgrade the version of Sf because I'm not the only guy to work on this project and I'm not the big boss. ;)

Comment: isMethod() was added in Symfony 2.1. If you are unable to use 2.1.*, then I would suggest reading the 2.0 documentation instead: <http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/index.html>